# Set scrollview size and position by code

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I've added a scrollView in Main.storyboard and made it the same size as the view and set the backgroundcolor to blue. 
But I'm having troubles with autolayout so I'm trying to deactivate the constraints by code (succeeded) and set the frame position and size with the following code inside viewDidLoad()

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.view.constraints())

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 200.0, 200.0)
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = (UIColor.redColor())
```

When I run the code the colour changes to red (so I've got that going for me, which is nice) but the scrollView doesn't change position or size.
What is the right syntax to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you set the frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews():

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
}
```

Trying to do this in viewDidLoad() will not work because scrollView is not yet in the view hierarchy at this point.

Note that you are only deactivating the constraints for the view and not its subviews in your code snippet. This may not be what you intended.

Also note that I'm not endorsing this as a way to fix constraint problems. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! This works! It's the perfect way for me to control the layout by code. I'll be using this until the auto layout is fixed (perhaps in the final version).